# Concatenate a column only if its not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sentence

i have a SQL Server table like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
PERSON
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   NAME   |   PHONE   |   PHONE1   |   PHONE2   |   PHONE_CONCAT  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   Name1  |   12345   |   Null     |   Null     |   Null
   Name2  |   Null    |   54774    |   Null     |   Null
   Name3  |   Null    |   Null     |   77841    |   Null
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is concatenate into PHONE_CONCAT the columns PHONE, PHONE1, and PHONE2 just when the value for one of those columns is !=null. So, in this case, the final value for the PHONE_CONCAT column will be:

```
------------------
PERSON
------------------
   PHONE_CONCAT  
------------------
   12345
   54774
   77841
 ------------------
```

Could u please help me perform this action?

I want to update the PHONE_CONCAT value, so I will need to execute an update on each row in table.

Comment: What if two columns have phone numbers?

Comment: One of our answers got to answer his requirement :) @GordonLinoff .

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?

```
select coalesce(t.phone, t.phone1, t.phone2) as phone_concat
from t;
```

This returns the *first* phone number that is not `NULL`.  That seems like the simplest way to get your desired result.

Comment: IMO, This answer is better than the other one, as supporting numeric types ;).

Comment: @shA.t . . . Phone numbers should not be stored as numbers.  The difference between this and Sagi's is simply what the OP intends when there are multiple values in a single row -- and the question is not clear on that.

Comment: This is actually also not 100% what the OP wants since this would provide a return value != NULL even when several columns are != NULL. Or at least that's what he has asked for.

Comment: @Jens . . . The OP *does* say "just when the value for one of those columns is !=null"; however, I'm not 100% sure that is the actual intention.  English is a tricky language, and it seems unlikely that the OP wants to return NULL if 2 or more columns have values.  It is definitely possible, and the OP should have clearer data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Although I do agree that this is most likely what the OP wanted, just assuming his English isn't good enough to reflect this and providing a different solution as a result is slightly insulting. With that being said, I did upvote your answer since I believe this is the best approach. I'm not saying you're at fault in any of this. If anything, the OP is at fault for not clarifying his intentions after questions were raised (and seemingly not ever coming back to SO after getting a useful answer, even if just for marking a solution).

Answer (score 4):

As a select statement :

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.phone,'') + COALESCE(t.phone1,'') + COALESCE(t.phone2,'') 
FROM PERSON t
```

Or if you want to update it:

```
UPDATE PERSON t
SET t.PHONE_CONCAT = COALESCE(t.phone,'') + COALESCE(t.phone1,'') + COALESCE(t.phone2,'')
```

Comment: why convert them all to empty strings first when you can just throw them all into coalesce?  also, this will produce weird results if more than one column has data.

Comment: I did that on purpose . I understood he wants to concatenate all the `NOT NULL` phone numbers together. I think he just choose a bad sample of data. @DForck42 . The question title was `Join two Columns into new column`

Comment: Definitely does not deserve a downvote.  This is likely to be what the OP wants, although concatenating phone numbers with no separators doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants: "What I want to do is concatenate into PHONE_CONCAT the columns PHONE, PHONE1, and PHONE2 *just when the value for one of those columns is !=null*. "

Comment: I am sorry , but the question is incomplete and lacking some required information in order to determine if Gordon or my answer is correct. @Jens

Comment: @sagi I fully agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH PERSON AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
 ('Name1' , '12345' , Null , Null , Null),
 ('Name2' , Null , '54774' , Null , Null),
 ('Name2a', Null , '54774' , Null , '4356'),
 ('Name3' , Null , Null , '77841' , Null))
 s( NAME , PHONE , PHONE1 , PHONE2 , PHONE_CONCAT )) 
SELECT NAME ,TRIM(CONCAT( PHONE + ' ', PHONE1 + ' ', PHONE2 + ' ', PHONE_CONCAT)) FROM PERSON
```

Will be:

```
NAME   
------ ----------------------
Name1  12345
Name2  54774
Name2a 54774 4356
Name3  77841

(4 rows affected)
```