# Create a custom column based on the values of three other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In this project I'm currently working on (I'm building a bridge between a desktop app and a new e-shop) there is a products table that has some spare columns defined that can be used for whatever reason the end user might need some custom data to be stored into.

So, the user needed to set a true/false flag to determine whether the products would appear in three different sliders... Unfortunately, the person who implemented this, didn't even use the same type of spare columns... So,

- Slider1's flag is stored in a `varchar(50)` column
- Slider2's flag is stored in a `float` column
- Slider3's flag is stored in a `float` column

Additionally I ran a `SELECT DISTINCT <column>` for each one of them to get an idea of the actual data stored in each column and got the following results:

- The `varchar` column has the following data stored in it:

| FLDSTRING1 |
| --- |
| NULL |
| '' |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 194276400456 |

- The `float` column has the following data stored:

| FLDFLOAT5 |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 0 |
| 1 |

- And the other `float` column has this:

| FLDFLOAT6 |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 1 |

Also, I ran the following query to find the different combinations of the data stored for each column:

```
SELECT FLDSTRING1, FLDFLOAT5, FLDFLOAT6
FROM MATERIAL
GROUP BY FLDSTRING1, FLDFLOAT5, FLDFLOAT6
```

and got the following combinations...

| FLDSTRING1 | FLDFLOAT5 | FLDFLOAT6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | 0 | NULL |
| NULL | 1 | NULL |
| NULL | 1 | 1 |
| '' | NULL | NULL |
| '' | NULL | 1 |
| 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 0 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 194276400456 | 0 | NULL |

What I need after all this introduction...

I want a concatenated string of three comma-separated values like this

- `NEWPROD` for when `FLDSTRING1` would evaluate to `true` - anything not NULL, 0, or ''
- `CUSTOM1` for when `FLDFLOAT5` would evaluate to `true` - basically the value 1
- `CUSTOM2` for when `FLDFLOAT6` would evaluate to `true` - again value 1

After some trial and error I managed to bring this to a point that it kind of works, in the sense that it brings the correct values, not comma-separated though...

```
SELECT 
    FLDSTRING1, FLDFLOAT5, FLDFLOAT6, 
    CONCAT(CASE WHEN ISNULL(FLDSTRING1, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE 'NEWPROD' END, 
           CASE WHEN ISNULL(FLDFLOAT5,  '') = '' THEN '' ELSE 'CUSTOM1' END,
           CASE WHEN ISNULL(FLDFLOAT6,  '') = '' THEN '' ELSE 'CUSTOM2' END) AS TAGS
FROM 
    MATERIAL
GROUP BY 
    FLDSTRING1, FLDFLOAT5, FLDFLOAT6;
```

| FLDSTRING1 | FLDFLOAT5 | FLDFLOAT6 | TAGS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| NULL | NULL | 1 | CUSTOM2 |
| NULL | 0 | NULL |  |
| NULL | 1 | NULL | CUSTOM1 |
| NULL | 1 | 1 | CUSTOM1CUSTOM2 |
| '' | NULL | NULL |  |
| '' | NULL | 1 | CUSTOM2 |
| 0 | NULL | NULL | NEWPROD |
| 0 | 0 | NULL | NEWPROD |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NEWPROD |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | NEWPRODCUSTOM2 |
| 1 | 0 | NULL | NEWPROD |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NEWPRODCUSTOM1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NEWPRODCUSTOM1CUSTOM2 |
| 194276400456 | 0 | NULL | NEWPROD |

Problem #1 is I don't quite understand how this works... I mean, value `0` isn't `''`, but still for the combination of `NULL 0 NULL` I get an empty value, which is what I wanted... But how does it do that?

And also, can someone update my final query to comma-separate the calculated `TAGS` column? Problem #2 is that I don't want it to contain just two commas, like `,,`, when the combination wouldn't justify any of the three values to appear... It should work like PHP's `implode()` works...

To help you help me with this, I'm including a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=19a9d8c56c24da16874ee986c7da9044) with the setup of the scenario I describe here... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: We don't need all that background information, in fact its going to put people off. What you are asking only requires the information from the fiddle and your desired results to make sense.

Comment: And in database land we refer to that as a column not a field.

Comment: @DaleK please feel free to edit my question however you think might prove beneficial to the community and at the same time drag people's attention to deal with it. It's not that I'm lazy yo do it myself... I'm just afraid that I might remove more info than it'd still be a complete description of my situation. Fun fact, I described it so thoroughly because I wasn't planning on providing a fiddle... Then I thought that I might get complaints that I didn't provide one, so I prepared one quickly, so here we are...

Comment: `CASE WHEN ISNULL(FLDSTRING1, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE 'NEWPROD' END` can/should be replaced with the less obtuse `CASE WHEN FLDSTRING1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'NEWPROD' END`

Comment: @Bohemian it completely alters the custom column, and not in the correct way... I mean, I was wondering how my query works for making 0 evaluate to false, and your solution did exactly that, it evaluates 0 to true!!! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=833e98b9a1282f9526f68733fa3a9e0d

Comment: Yes. I see that now - I had to read your question a couple of times to find the key point. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to concat values into a comma (or other separator) separated list, which *ignores nulls*.

To use `CONCAT_WS()`, you want to pass it a true `NULL` if the value is "blank" (by your definition), otherwise your custom label:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  FLDSTRING1,
  FLDFLOAT5,
  FLDFLOAT6,
  CONCAT_WS(',',
    CASE WHEN FLDSTRING1 IS NULL OR FLDSTRING1 = '' OR FLDSTRING1 = '0' THEN NULL ELSE 'NEWPROD' END,
    CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT5 IS NULL OR FLDFLOAT5 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'CUSTOM1' END,
    CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT6 IS NULL OR FLDFLOAT6 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'CUSTOM2' END) AS TAGS
FROM MATERIAL
```

Replaced `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT` because it's simpler and (here) achieves the same thing.

---

If `CONCAT_WS` is not available:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  FLDSTRING1,
  FLDFLOAT5,
  FLDFLOAT6,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN FLDSTRING1 IS NULL OR FLDSTRING1 = '' OR FLDSTRING1 = '0' THEN 'X' ELSE 'NEWPROD' END,
    ',',
    CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT5 IS NULL OR FLDFLOAT5 = 0 THEN 'X' ELSE 'CUSTOM1' END,
    ',',
    CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT6 IS NULL OR FLDFLOAT6 = 0 THEN 'X' ELSE 'CUSTOM2' END
  ), ',X', ''), 'X,', ''), 'X', '') AS TAGS
FROM MATERIAL
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=555f3f419d0708b6f9ad31a24cf0dfac).

Comment: Ouch! I tried to be as descriptive as possible, and I forgot to mention the SQL Server version that runs on this... It's SQL Server 2014... CONCAT_WS isn't available on it...

Comment: Then it's going to be a bit painful...

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361969/concatenate-a-column-only-if-its-not-null but I don't know how to implement it in my situation where there are already a lot of if's and then's...

Comment: @FayeD. Help is at hand. See updated answer.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as well as ggordon's, but to be fair towards both of you, I can't accept either one as the accepted answer, as each of them has their pros and cons. Your approach (the non-CONCAT_WS I mean) is much more difficult to grasp than ggordon's, and ggordon's answer (at least the initial one) didn't evaluate 0 as false (like your early version did also). So a combination of the two is what I finally ended up doing. Thank you very much for your persistence in helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2014, instead of `CONCAT_WS` you may try `STUFF` as shown below. By prepending the delimiter `,` before all strings ,the `STUFF` will remove the first comma found.

```sql
SELECT 
    FLDSTRING1, 
    FLDFLOAT5, 
    FLDFLOAT6, 
    STUFF(
        CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN FLDSTRING1 IS NULL OR FLDSTRING1 IN ('0','') THEN '' THEN '' ELSE ',NEWPROD' END, 
            CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT5 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',CUSTOM1' END,
            CASE WHEN FLDFLOAT6 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',CUSTOM2' END
        ),
        1,1,''
    ) AS TAGS
FROM @MATERIAL
GROUP BY FLDSTRING1, FLDFLOAT5, FLDFLOAT6;
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=53eb835ace8e65328ffc47b37f7f15e8)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Actually this introduced the same unwanted behavior of @Bohemian 's answer, that it evaluates 0 as true also... But at least it solved the comma-separation! I combined my query and yours, and finally it worked exactly as I want it to! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f431911d91d63323f77e49a50c8f79b5

Comment: @FayeD. I'm glad it helped. I just updated the explanation and demo and the case expression with `OR FLDSTRING1 IN ('0','')` to facilitate these arguments. But yours works too!